# identify malicious file upload in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, html

I have problem with file upload in java script.As an example say if you have client side validation to check MIME type of file uploads.Any one can rename the file in to correct type and change the MIME type and upload.So validation wont work ? 
Ex : on client side i'm checking file is a pdf type.So any person can rename a exe file to pdf and upload to the server.Is there any way to validate those kind of scenarios in  client side ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't even guarantee that your client-side code is being used to post a file to your upload URL, so no. You have to validate the file on your *server*.

Comment: Don't overthink this. Once a file has been renamed from .exe to .pdf it will just be an invalid PDF file, it won't suddenly execute unless somebody renames it back to .exe.

Comment: To expand on @Pointy's comment, client side validation is a courtesy to make your user's experience better. Server side validation is a necessity to ensure the security of your application. Any well designed system should do both, always.

Comment: You should consider filtering by extension in client side like a help for users to find files, ex, not including images if they are looking for documents, but never as a validation, you must validate everything in server side.

Comment: server-side validation is important. use the correct mime-types. Security should be your first priority not just adding fancy insecure features.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible with client-side validation, because you can not be sure that client-side code is even run.

Every modern browser can disable JavaScript or modify it. Relying on client-side validations for security is **incredibly bad practice** and should only ever be used to improve UX, such as telling the user that the username they chose is already taken, etc.

What you need to do is verify the file on the server. Given that you mentioned PDF files, I would suggest you to use a library to parse them and verify that the user is indeed uploading a valid PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.also what if user have to validate the file before uploads ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "verify" and what you want to prevent. If you want to prevent an attacker from uploading malicious things, you can't stop them with client-side code because they don't play by your rules.